# Best Paypal mobile integration option for Subscription services

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, stripe-payments, paypal-subscriptions

I have a native mobile app in which I want users to subscribe for a monthly fee. I started by integrating with the native PayPal SDKs and use future payments, but in that case I'm in charge of processing the payments every month.  I want a more automatic way where users approve their subscription and PayPal automatically posts the payments every month.

I have also started looking at Stripe, so if there is a solution using another library I would be glad to hear of that too.

Comment: Stripe won't support Paypal. Braintree would though

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I work for Stripe.)

Stripe does support recurring payments with the "subscriptions" feature. You can read more about it here:

- https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions
- https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions

To implement this in a mobile app, you'd need to use the [iOS SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and/or the [Android SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android). Both SDKs offer the same functionality: the ability to turn card information into a token, by exchanging the information directly between the user's device and Stripe's servers.

This way, the sensitive card information never hits your server, which greatly reduces the burden of PCI compliance. You can read more here: https://support.stripe.com/questions/do-i-need-to-be-pci-compliant-what-do-i-have-to-do. (This article talks about [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) and [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout), but the mobile SDKs serve the same purpose.)

Once a token has been created, you'd need to send it to an external server, where you would use it to [create a customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) and [a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription), as explained in the subscriptions documentation I linked above.

The reason why this needs to be done on an external server and not in the app itself is because aside from the creation of card tokens, all other API requests need to be sent with your secret API key. You cannot embed or otherwise provide the secret API key to your app, as an attacker could extract it and use it for malicious purposes (they could refund past charges, use your account to test stolen card numbers, etc.).

Comment: Can you provide any sample project